# Fast doubling Fibonacci Python generator sequence

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm having troubles try to create a Fast doubling Fibonacci python generator, using the following.

Given F(k) and F(k+1), we can calculate these:

```
F(2k) = F(k)[2F(k + 1) − F(k)]
F(2k+1) = F(k+1)^2 + F(k)^2
```

I've got the following for the simplest (slow) Fibonacci generator:

```
def fib_generator():
    n = 1
    n0 = 1
    while True:
        yield n
        n, n0 = n + n0, n
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Neither generating *all* Fibonacci numbers nor generating some fast-growing sub-sequence makes sense to me. The former is better done with the simple one you already have, and the latter is missing many. What's the point then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation could be:

```
from itertools import count

def fast_fib_generator():
    F = [1, 1]
    yield 1
    yield 1
    for k in count(1):
        F.append(F[k] ** 2 + F[k - 1] ** 2)
        yield F[-1]

        F.append(F[k] * (2 * F[k + 1] - F[k]))
        yield F[-1]


for x in fast_fib_generator():
    print x
```

First results:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci(number):
    numbers = [0, 1]
    while len(numbers) < number:
        numbers[len(numbers):len(numbers)] = [numbers[len(numbers)-2] + numbers[len(numbers)-1]]
    return numbers
```

First get a list of the fibonacci sequence... Then loop through.

```
def fib_gen(number):
    for iter in fibonacci(number):
        print iter
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
num=int(input("Enter length of series required"))
fiblist=[]
for i in range(num):
    if i==0 or i==1:
        fiblist.append(i)
    else:
        temp=fiblist[i-2]+fiblist[i-1]
        fiblist.append(temp)
print(*fiblist,sep=' ')
```

Comment: The OP has asked for a fast doubling Fibonacci sequence, what you have posted is a normal Fibonacci sequence recursive function, please read the question again.